# NestJs swagger missing base path

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, nestjs

Everything works fine on local machine. The problem arises after deployment.
After deployment, `/querybuilder` gets appended to the base url.
So,

```
http://localhost:80/helloworld
```

would become

```
http://52.xxx.xxx.139/querybuilder/helloworld
```

Swagger page at:

http://52.xxx.xxx.139/querybuilder/swagger/

When I execute a method through swagger ui page:
This is what I see in networks tab:

Request URL: http://52.xxx.xxx.139/

Controller:

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

**Main.ts**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
  .setTitle('Query Builder - MongoDb Parser')
  .setDescription("This is Query Builder's MongoDb Parser takes database agnostic queries and transpiles it into native MongoDb query.")
  .setVersion('1.0')
  .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);
  await app.listen(80);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 7):

In most cases the most appropriate way to achieve this is by using [setGlobalPrefix](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/global-prefix#global-prefix) method which adds prefix to your API endpoints and URL used by swagger.

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.setGlobalPrefix('querybuilder');
```

However, if your routing is handled by external server (e.g. nginx), you can add the prefix only to the URL used by swagger using `addServer` method.

```js
const options = new DocumentBuilder()
  .setTitle('Query Builder - MongoDb Parser')
  .addServer('/querybuilder')
```

Comment: I was trying to use addBasePath - but it seems to have been deprecated in favor of addServer

Comment: `app.setGlobalPrefix` has to be called before `SwaggerModule.setup`. Otherwise globalPrefix will not be honored by swagger.